# Non-progressive eventive sentences in the present tense

Tags: present-tense

When using a non-progressive eventive sentence in the present tense, it typically cannot describe a particular event: it often describes a habit or a generalization. E.g. if one says "John smokes a pipe", the listener would understand that this is a habit.

However, if a novel writer uses "John smokes a pipe" as a title of a chapter, the reader would understand that the chapter will describe a specific event where John smoked a pipe.

Why? Is there any name to this phenomena?

Comment: Yes, there is a name for it. The sentences and noun and verb phrases are called **Generic**. There is some [information about them here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/generics.html).

Comment: ... For 'some information' read 'the book'.

Comment: You did say "a habit or a generalization," right? Did you Google around a bit?

Answer (score 1):

You ask 'Why'.

Originally the chapter might have been entitled, e.g.

*CHAPTER V 
In which John smokes a pipe.*

This indicates that smoking is probably not a habit of John's. He does it only in this part of the narrative.

**Example**
The Unwilling Adventurer

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nYCH-qnPXHkC&pg=PP8&dq=%22chapter+5+in+which%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JNKWVaj_OYOo-QGS5IGIBg&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22chapter%205%20in%20which%22&f=false

Answer (score 0):

See:

> In linguistics and rhetoric, the historic present or **historical
>   present** (also called **dramatic present** or **narrative present**)
>   refers to the employment of the present tense when narrating past
>   events. It is widely used in writing about history in Latin and some
>   modern European languages; in English it is used above all in
>   historical chronicles (listing a series of events); it is also used in
>   fiction, for 'hot news' (as in headlines), and in everyday
>   conversation (Huddleston & Pullum 2002: 129–131). In conversation, it
>   is particularly common with 'verbs of communication' such as tell,
>   write, and say (and in colloquial uses, go) (Leech 2002: 7). Historic
>   present is the form recognised by the Oxford English Dictionary,
>   whereas historical present is the form in Merriam Webster.
>
> Literary critics and grammarians have said that the historic present
>   has the effect of making past events more vivid. More recently,
>   analysts of its use in conversation have argued that it functions not
>   by making an event present, but **by marking segments of a narrative,
>   foregrounding events (that is, signalling that one event is
>   particularly important, relevant to others) and marking a shift to
>   evaluation** (Brinton 1992: 221).
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present)

Comment: This is just not it. The OP has already recognized and mentioned "generalization."